# SQL query For Latest date/time Stamp record for each ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

Please help to sort below list TABLE,

```
ID NAME DATE TIME STATUS
```

ID is unique, Name, Date, Time, Status keeps changing in database.

I need output list, having **Latest** STATUS, DATE AND TIME stamps for each user ID

[image]

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Also, if your user id is unique like you claim, the latest version of the other fields is going to be whatever their current values are ...

Comment: In your screenshot, ID is far from unique.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm just biggener. unique ID mean, I have to order the report for each user ID,

Comment: I'm using SQL server database.

Comment: What is your database? The `ID` is not `Unique` as you said. What is your expected results? What did you try? What is the datatype of `C_Date` and `C_Time` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use window functions for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc, time desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Alternatively, if you have a table with one row per customer, then `apply` might be best:

```
select t.*
from customers c cross apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from t
      where t.id = c.id
      order by date desc, time desc
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE C_Time = 
  (SELECT max(C_Time) FROM table t1 WHERE C_Date = 
    (SELECT max(C_Date) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.ID = t2.ID)
  );
```

This gives you the entries for the highest `C_Date` and `C_Time` values for every `ID`

Comment: Yes, I just need row (s) for each ID, where C_Date and C_Time having highest values regardless of the status.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T T1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID,
               CName,
               MAX(CDate) CDate,
               MAX(CTime) CTime
        FROM T
        GROUP BY ID,
                 CName
    ) T2 
ON T1.CDate = T2.CDate 
   AND 
   T1.CTime = T2.CTime 
   AND T1.CName = T2.CName;
```

Which will return

```
+---------------------+----------+--------+----+-------+
|        CDate        |  CTime   | Status | ID | CName |
+---------------------+----------+--------+----+-------+
| 22/12/2018 00:00:00 | 16:27:57 |      1 |  1 | A     |
| 21/12/2018 00:00:00 | 15:41:13 |      4 |  2 | B     |
| 20/12/2018 00:00:00 | 12:35:27 |      3 |  2 | C     |
| 21/12/2018 00:00:00 | 15:29:46 |      4 |  3 | D     |
+---------------------+----------+--------+----+-------+
```

OR

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T T1 INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID,
               MAX(CDate) CDate,
               MAX(CTime) CTime
        FROM T
        GROUP BY ID
    ) T2 
ON T1.CDate = T2.CDate 
   AND 
   T1.CTime = T2.CTime;
```

Which will return

```
+---------------------+----------+--------+----+-------+
|        CDate        |  CTime   | Status | ID | CName |
+---------------------+----------+--------+----+-------+
| 22/12/2018 00:00:00 | 16:27:57 |      1 |  1 | A     |
| 21/12/2018 00:00:00 | 15:41:13 |      4 |  2 | B     |
| 21/12/2018 00:00:00 | 15:29:46 |      4 |  3 | D     |
+---------------------+----------+--------+----+-------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b1fcb97878cee32ecaf00c7d5ba516fd)**

Comment: C_Date C_Time STATUS L_UID C_Name
20181122 162757 1 1 A
20181122 151310 2 1 A
20181121 154113 4 2 B
20181121 145028 4 2 B
20181120 123527 3 3 C
20181121 152946 4 4 D
20181121 152934 3 4 D
20181121 152905 2 4 D

Comment: 1st output will solve the problem, please let me know what is T in statement FROM T T1 INNER JOIN and what is  T2,  as I have only one table to work with. Can you please write expression for provided table accordingly for my understanding..

Comment: @ASEE `T` is your table, `T1` is an alias for your table and `T2` is an alias for the subquey, please see the demo. and please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)